# SharePoint error: Web application at xxxx could not be found

Tags: c#, .net, sharepoint-2010

When I try to execute this code:

```
SPSite siteCollection = new SPSite(@"http://sp-devxxx:10000/");
```

It throws the following error:

> The Web application at
>   http://sp-devxxx:10000 could not be
>   found. Verify that you have typed the
>   URL correctly. If the URL should be
>   serving existing content, the system
>   administrator may need to add a new
>   request URL mapping to the intended
>   application.

I can hit this site from my web browser, it is compiling in x64, my account has read/write access to the content db, the code is running on the server that the site is running on and there exists an access mapping for this site.  Why would it be throwing this error?

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/806533/sharepoint-spsite

Comment: Yes, I am running as myself and I am an admin/have full access.

Comment: Do you have PowerShell on the server? (if you're running sp2010, I guess you are?)

Comment: @Sam, yes that's the machine name.  @xOn, No i don't think it's on the machine. why?

Comment: I would look around alternate access mapping on this. Unfortunately I have no other clues.

Comment: Hmm, anything specific I should look for?

Comment: Is this a console app, an asp.net application or what?

Comment: This is in a windows forms test harness.  When done testing it will be moved to a custom timer job.

Comment: Is the account you use the web browser with, the same as the account you are logged on to the server?

Comment: @djeeg, Yes they are the same.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

OK, after hours of pain i finally found the problem....

I had to add myself to the WSS_ADMIN_WPG group on the server.  Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 13):

Change Target Platform to x64 as Sharepoint 2010 runs only in 64 bit mode

Answer (score 3):

The account that is the identity of the app pool in my environment was already a member of WSS_ADMIN_WPG. I installed my web service locally. Using the external domain name such as

```
SPSite siteCollection = new SPSite(@"http://mydomain:123");
```

failed, reporting the same error as the poster (even though it is reachable from a browser on the same machine). The following worked

```
SPSite siteCollection = new SPSite(@"http://localhost");
```

I have yet to figure out why.

Comment: There is option in Sharepoint: Alternate access mapping. May be you need to add external domain there. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263208%28v=office.12%29.aspx

Comment: +1 Maybe because localhost automatically maps to current server, on which you are running the script targetting it. As in the hosts file (but no need for hosts file)

Answer (score 2):

In a console application using visual studio 2012 it was changing the Target framework to 3.5 for me....

Comment: This was the same for me except I was running in a Windows Forms App. I was porting over existing code to a new project that happened to be .Net 4.5 and it wouldn't return the site. Changing it to 3.5 resolved the issue; I wonder if this is because we are on SharePoint 2010?

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I re-opened Visual Studio 2012 running as Administrator, and the problem is solved.

Answer (score 1):

In case the user's account is already a member of `WSS_ADMIN_WPG` and still the issue persists, As mentioned by Tim.

Try the following steps:

1. Go to Project Properties
2. Build Tab
3. Change the Platform Target value to `Any CPU` from the drop down.

It resolved the problem for our console Application.

Answer (score 1):

`Add-SPShellAdmin -UserName domain\username` did the trick for me. The [documentation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607596.aspx) says that it adds user to the **SharePoint_Shell_Access** role in the farm configuration database only, and also ensures the user is added to the **WSS_Admin_WPG** local group on each server in the farm.

Answer (score 0):

Have you disabled the loopback check?

http://sptwentyten.wordpress.com/2010/03/06/disable-the-loopback-check-via-powershell/

http://www.jeremytaylor.net/2010/05/24/sharepoint-disable-loopback-check-disableloopbackcheck-dword-in-registry/

Comment: Gave it a shot but no dice.  I think this only applies to 401.1 errors, which isn't what i'm getting, correct?

Answer (score 0):

Try Logging on as the Farm Admin account.  Or, granting the required SQL Server Roles to the account you are using.

Answer (score 0):

I have a Web API on the SharePoint server that we use as a medium to get data from our own database. This Web API was attempting to open the website, and I was receiving the same error. I had to make sure that the Application Pool identity being used had access to open the website.

I set the identity of the Web API application pool to *SharePointServerFarm*, which is the identity that my SharePoint web applications use.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I needed to add the user **db_owner** permission to the *SharePoint_Config*, *SharePoint_AdminContent* and *WSS_Content* databases, following the suggestions in [this blog](https://www.logbinder.com/blog?p=61b9a9e0-cbd8-496f-8b04-0bd86549b7bf).

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old and answered thread, but none of the above worked for me, and here's what did for future reference:

I have a windows forms application creating an instance of a sharepoint 2013 site and gives the mentioned error when trying to initialize the `SPSite`, after some search I've found the following reference that suggests (among other possible resolutions) the issue could happen when running the code on a machine different than the one running the actual Site, and yes it worked flawlessly when I moved the app to the other machine.

I know this is not a radical solution, but at least you know the issue.

reference:

[Common issue: new SPSite API call returns "The Web application at http://server:port/ could not be found."](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/stefan_gossner/2011/09/18/common-issue-new-spsite-api-call-returns-the-web-application-at-httpserverport-could-not-be-found/)

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue while running my code as "exe" file. Problem solved by running `cmd` as administrator. Hope this help someone.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's quite long time ago, but in my case, I had to do 2 things:

1. give access to config db, user is programmatically able to open SPSite-object

```
Add-SPShellAdmin -username [domain]\[username]
```

2. give access to content db, user is programmatically able to open SPWeb-object

```
Add-SPShellAdmin -username [domain]\[username] -database [content db guid]
```

You can get the Guid of content db by running following `Get-SPContentDatabase -webapplication [web application url]`

You can find here the original answer of Timo Pitkäranta: https://blog.stefan-gossner.com/2011/09/18/common-issue-new-spsite-api-call-returns-the-web-application-at-httpserverport-could-not-be-found/