# Open spweb in windows service

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2010

I want to check documents properties in SharePoint library. Please tell me how to open SharePoint website in windows service.
I am using following code in windows service, it gives "site not found error".

```
SPSite spSite = new SPSite("http://xyz/sites/abc");
```

Detail Error is,

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: The Web application at http://xyz/sites/abc could not be found. Verify that you have typed the URL correctly. If the URL should be serving existing content, the system administrator may need to add a new request URL mapping to the intended application.
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite..ctor(SPFarm farm, Uri requestUri, Boolean contextSite, SPUserToken userToken)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite..ctor(String requestUrl)
   at SSP_DL_notify_service.Service1.GetMail(Object sender, ElapsedEventArgs args) in C:\Users\pqr\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\SSP_DL_notify_service\SSP_DL_notify_service\Service1.cs:line 54
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is fine.

Are you sure that `http://xyz/sites/abc` is a site? Is the URL correct?

If the URL is correct then check if you have required permissions to open it.

**EDIT:**

Check this thread also: [SharePoint error: Web application at xxxx could not be found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4787349/sharepoint-error-web-application-at-xxxx-could-not-be-found)

Comment: here i given dummy url, can we open spsite in windows service ?

Comment: Yes, technically this is possible.

Comment: thanks, but i m running same in windows service it gives site not found exception. i checked permissions also..

Comment: Which account does your service use to run(check LogOn tab in service properties)?

Comment: Check the thread that I mentioned in last edit - maybe it will help you somehow.